# C# start Outlook in different security context

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-10

We have a WPF application need to display a new Outlook item, allow user to edit before send. The application start with administrator privileges, so if user's Outlook opened already, then there's an error when getting Outlook instance. How to solve it? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: You need to provide what you have tried so far. It is impossible for someone to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't automate Outlook if it is run under different security context. But you can detect such cases trying to get an Outlook instance using the [Marshal.GetActiveObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject(v=vs.110).aspx) method which obtains a running instance of the specified object from the running object table (ROT). For example:

```
    Outlook.Application GetApplicationObject()
    {

        Outlook.Application application = null;

        // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
        {

            // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
            application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;

            if(application == null)
               MessageBox.Show("You need to run Outlook under the same security context");
        }
        else
        {

            // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
            application = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            nameSpace = null;
        }

        // Return the Outlook Application object.
        return application;
    }
```

So, when the `Outlook.exe` process exists and you can't get the object all you can do is to ask users to run the application under the same security context.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do short of starting your app in the same security context.